# Plot values not updated in OpenCV's VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to plot facial key points on the video frame using Open CV Video Capture. I am using a trained pytorch CNN model. Here is the code:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        face_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    sample = cv.resize(face_gray, (96, 96))
    sample = sample.astype('float32')/255
    sample = np.asarray(sample).reshape(1,96,96)
    sample = torch.from_numpy(sample).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
    output = saved_model(sample)
    output = output.view(-1, 2).detach()
    output = (output * 48) + 48
    output = output.cpu().numpy()
    print(output)
    for i in range(15):
        cv.circle(frame, (output[i][0], output[i][1]), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input dimension: torch.Tensor([1,1,96,96]), 1 grayscale image

Output dimension: torch.Tensor([15, 2]), (x,y) of 15 facial key points

When the face is detected (using Haar Cascade) in the Video Capture, the output values are the same due to which the key points plot does not change.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code block. The only possibility of error that can happen is when you have a static face in the video frame and that is detected as the last face by the HaarCascade detector. By looking at your code block, it is apparent that you are trying to detect keypoints only one face per video frame. Try moving the `sample = ...`, `output = ...`, and `for ...:` block to render keypoints into the `for ...` iterator of faces.

Comment: That was the case, indeed. I figured it out and came here to edit my question. Thanks anyway. @SriRaghuMalireddi kindly post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code block. The only possibility of error that can happen is when you have a static face in the video frame and that is detected as the last face by the HaarCascade detector. By looking at your code block, it is apparent that you are trying to detect keypoints only one face per video frame. Try moving the `sample = ...`, `output = ...`, and `for ...:` block to render keypoints into the `for ...` iterator of faces.

The code block after suggested edits will look like this:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        face_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        # Push this block into for iterator of faces
        sample = cv.resize(face_gray, (96, 96))
        sample = sample.astype('float32')/255
        sample = np.asarray(sample).reshape(1,96,96)
        sample = torch.from_numpy(sample).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        output = saved_model(sample)
        output = output.view(-1, 2).detach()
        output = (output * 48) + 48
        output = output.cpu().numpy()
        print(output)
        for i in range(15):
            cv.circle(frame, (output[i][0], output[i][1]), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        # End block

    cv.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't handling the case of `len(faces) > 0` initially for some number of iterations, then `len(faces) == 0` subsequently. Should that happen, `face_gray` will retain its prior value, and you'll be drawing onto a new `frame` based on a stale `face_gray`.

Comment: I faced the initial problem with just one face in the frame. Resolved it by making two changes. I placed the code from `sample = ...` until `cv.circle...` inside `faces` loop and re-scaled the key points' x and y values to match the original frame.